# What does CombineSelector do in Linq

Tags: linq, selector

I'm looking at CombineSelector in reflector.

Can someone explain what it does exactly.

Comment: Enumerable.CombineSelectors

Answer (score 0):

First of all, keep in mind that it's a private method, intended for internal use.  Not only aren't you supposed to use it, without going to a lot of trouble, you CAN'T use it.

Simply put, it takes two delegates, and creates a new function which takes a value, and calls the first delegate with the parameter value, and then calls the second with the return value of the first.

Hence:

```
var func = Enumerable.CombineSelector<int, double, string>(x=> x*100.0, 
                                                           y=> y.ToString());
```

would be roughly the same as:

```
var func = x=> (x*100.0).ToString();
```

which would be roughly the same as:

```
string func(int x) { double y = x * 100.0
                     return y.ToString();
                   }
```

Comment: Would I be right in saying that chaining Linq Select or Where queries does not affect perfomance?